# How do I transform a vertical line with a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have a vertical line defined as:$$x=c$$where $c$ is some constant, and I want to transform it with a matrix:$$\begin{bmatrix}m_{00} & m_{01}\\m_{10} & m_{11}\end{bmatrix}$$and end with a line with the format:$$y=ax+b.$$How would the math work out? I can easily see how to calculate the $a$ value, as it is just given by the right column vector of matrix's rise over run:$$a=\frac{m_{11}}{m_{01}}$$So now I'm left with the question of how to calculate b?

Comment: Using only a matrix can not do what you want, because $A \cdot 0 = 0$ for any matrix $A$. You might be searching for an affine transform of the form $v \mapsto A\cdot v + v_0$, where $A$ is a matrix and $v_0$ a vector.

Comment: Your calculation of the a value is not right as you would need to apply the matrix transformation to two points and calculate the gradient based on those points after the transformation. Using (c,0) and (c,1) tell you that the gradient after the transformation will indeed be a ratio of two of the entries in the matrix, but the ratio does not tell you the absolute value of either - there are infinitely many numbers that will give you the right gradient, but each pair will get you a different value of b.

Comment: im not sure if i made it clear that the line is vertical. Unless i have completely misunderstood something, any vertical line will have the same gradient as the vertical unit vector after transformation. What youre saying i should be doing is exactly what im already doing for any non-vertical line

Comment: See my comment to your answer below. Are you trying to get the entries of a matrix that map a vertical line to a target straight line or do you know the matrix already and just want to know where the transformation takes a given vertical line? My point is that if you make $m_{11} = 2$ and $m_{01}=1$ then a is the same as $m_{11} = 4$ and $m_{01}=2$ but both cannot be the same transformation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just after posting i had a realization.

We know a point the old line went through $(c, 0)$. If we transform this like it was a vector, by multiplying with the matrix, it should end up a place the new line will go through. And by knowing a point it need to go through and a slope, b is given by:$$b=ax-y$$Edit: i will just crunch the algebra for any future readers:
Let $p$ be the point that the $\begin{bmatrix}c\\0\end{bmatrix}$ ends up on. That means:$$p=\begin{bmatrix}m_{00}&m_{01}\\m_{10}&m_{11}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}c\\0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}m_{00}c\\m_{10}c\end{bmatrix}$$And then inserting the coordinates of $p$ into our equation for b we get:$$b=am_{00}c-m_{10}c$$

Comment: Is the question how to determine the entries of the matrix that will transform from one line to another, or how to determine where it ends up given we have the entries of the transformation? If the first, you need to get the entries of the matrix in terms of a and b - you need to have 4 expressions. If the second, yes, just apply the known matrix to points like you say. Matrix multiplication and the formula for a straight line is enough. :)

Comment: Already have the entries for the transformation, i'm sorry, i should have been more clear in my question.

Comment: But now you have worked out how to do that, you should think about how you would solve the reverse problem. ;)

Comment: It is an much more interesting problem for sure, but we haven't even started on linear algebra in school yet, so for now i think it would take too much reading and too many youtube videos before im quite at the level of solving that. :)

Comment: It's nice to see you are thinking ahead then. :) It might take a bit long to explain if you are just starting out, but it is not so difficult once you know that there is a standard form of how to do any rotations and scalings. It can be worked out using a combination of trigonometry, matrix multiplication and knowledge of straight line equations. :)

Answer (score 0):

You would perform a rotation to get the gradient correct and then a scaling to change the y-intercept from the one you have after rotation to the desired value of b. You need to know the form of the matrix for a rotation of a given angle, a way to calculate the angle you want, then calculate where the y-intercept will end up, call it p, and know the form of a matrix to scale by a factor of b/p. Finally need to compose the matrices to get the answer in the form of a 2 x 2 matrix and be careful to do so in the correct order as matrices are not generally commutative!

Edit: As per the comment above, it will not work for c=0 as p will be zero in the above.

Comment: If you take a look at my own answer im pretty sure thats an easier way, but please point out any flaws in that logic.